# Spring Boot 2 MongoDB @TypeAlias does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In SpringBoot 1 TypeAlias("name") does work as expected but if I migrate to SpringBoot 2 it doesn't instantiate the classes correctly.

```
@Document(collection = "test")
@TypeAlias("y")
public class TestY extends Test {

    private String y;

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```
@Document(collection = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    protected String id;

    public Test() {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
@Document(collection = "test")
@TypeAlias("x")
public class TestX extends Test {

    private String x;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

**Executions:**

If I only load the instances -> Test instances should be TestX or TestY but they are all Test

`List<Test> test = testRepository.findAll();`

If I save before the entities -> Test instances after loading are instantiated right as TestX and TestY

```
        TestY y = new TestY();
        y.setY("y");
        testRepository.save(y);

        TestX x = new TestX();
        x.setX("x");
        testRepository.save(x);
        List<Test> test = testRepository.findAll();
```

In Spring Boot 1 it works as expected.

**Dependencies**

before: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.5.21.RELEASE

after: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE

**Repositories**

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, String> {

}
```

Comment: Please add your dependencies list based on the used build tool (Maven, Gradle...) and how / what have you upgraded your dependencies (before - after).

Comment: before: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.5.21.RELEASE
after: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE

Comment: Could you add your `Repository`(ies) declaration(s) as well?

Comment: I added the repository, but it is only the default one.

Answer (score -1):

*Spring Data* relies on the declared (generic *typed*) repositories to handle your entities.

In order to be able to use polymorphism, with sub-types being read and stored as their concrete types, you have to declare a `Repository` for each of the persisting entities:

```java
@Repository
public interface TestYRepository extends MongoRepository<TestY, String> {}

@Repository
public interface TestXRepository extends MongoRepository<TestX, String> {}
```

Comment: In spring data 1 it worked as I described above and it also works if I store the entities.